# How to design test plan when it's not basic authentication? How to know which authentication is used in a given web based software?

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I was trying to load test a web based banking software's "LOGIN" portion. I have used http authorization manager but it didn't work as expected. Even if I insert incorrect password it gives positive test result. I've tried to parameterized user & password using CSV file, still same result. I tried to record the login process using blazemeter, But for some reason it only record home page, the procedure I am going through later is not recording.

1. How should I design my test?
2. I don't think the software I am trying to test is using Basic Authentication. Is there any way to know what kind of authentication is a software or website is using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your test design is correct, if your login is not successful most probably it's due to missing or incorrectly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start). In the majority of cases you cannot just replay the recorded script, modern web applications rely on dynamic parameters which are being used for [client-side state tracking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), [security](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf) and so on. So you need to "design" your test as follows:

   - Open login page
   - Extract dynamic parameters using suitable JMeter [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
   - Replace recorded hard-coded values with the [variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from Post-Processors
   - Replace recorded credentials with the variables from the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

   It might be the case it will be sufficient to add a HTTP Cookie Manager to your test plan

   With regards to "positive" test result - JMeter treats response as successful if the system under test responds with [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) below 400. You can add [Response Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to set additional pass criteria
2. You can guess the authentication scheme used by looking at [WWW-Authenticate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/WWW-Authenticate) response header